# Ubuntu Terminal: C program (or other solutions) to kill processes running on a specific port and start xampp

Tags: command-line, c, kill

Can anyone help me? The program's objective is to kill the processes running on port 443 and to then start `xampp` automatically.

What I've done:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {
    system("netstat -tulpn | grep :443");
    /* If 443 is busy (kill all)*/
    /*next -> */ system("/opt/lampp/xampp start");
}
```

Comment: You're trying to kill a fly with a sledgehammer, do you really need to use `C`? Is this for a didactic purpose?

Comment: I just I used c because I know it's possible, but I accept any solutions :)
Its not didactic purpose....

Comment: You want to kill a process? Do you know the name of the process? Or the process ID?

Comment: @Dragon21 I recommend you [edit] your question to clarify explicitly that you do not specifically require a C solution. It appears some people are voting to close this question because they think it's primarily about C programming and not process management. If you edit your question to clarify your actual needs and goals, that may be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `C` (note that `main()` usually returns an `int`):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int ret;

    ret=system("fuser -k 443/tcp; /opt/lampp/xampp start");
    return ret;
}
```

Or simply using `bash`:

```
fuser -k 443/tcp; /opt/lampp/xampp start
```

Using `;` in place of `&&` in either methods makes `/opt/lampp/xampp start` execute despite `fuser -k 443/tcp` not killing any process.

Comment: But If 443 not busy I have that: "sh: 1: kill: No such process" and xampp don't start :(

Comment: @Dragon21 You asked how to kill process 443, which is the process you're actually trying to kill?

Comment: 443 but if I stop xampp and try start with that script he dont start. Maybe because 443 is not busy now and xampp command not run next.

Comment: Not the process, the port 433

Comment: 443 is always busy when I turn on my pc with vmware

Comment: @Dragon21 You're trying to kill a process running on port 443? Please clarify this, otherwise my answer is totally invalid. Also what is *the name* of the process you're trying to kill? If you're actually trying to kill process 443 see the update: using `;` in place of `&&` will make `/opt/lampp/xampp start` start despite `kill -9 443` not killing any process.

Comment: yes, I'm trying to kill a process running on port 443.

Comment: @Dragon21 Ok see the update

Comment: and again +1 ;)

Comment: Or with awk ;) `netstat -tulpn | awk '$4 ~ /\.[0-9]{1,}:443/ && $6 ~ /[0-9]*\// {match($6,"[0-9]+",a)} END { print a[0] }'`

Comment: "awk" look cool, I need learn about

Answer (score 6):

To kill a process on a port you can do:

`$ fuser -n tcp -k 443 && /opt/lampp/xampp start`

Change the `&&` to `;` if you want it to start xampp no matter if there was anything running on that port or not.

Comment: +1 for an actual solution without a counterproductive C wrapping around it.